# Recursion theorem for ordinals proof

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

I'm trying to understand the proof of the recursion principle of ordinals, the theorem is:
[image]

The proof of this theorem uses this other theorem:
[image]

The proof is pretty long (I'm sorry) so I will try to highlight the main steps and you can only read the green parts:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The part I don't understand is the part highlighted in red, shouldn't this proof show that $A=\mathscr{O}$. Could you guys please explain me how the result of this theorem follows from the transinite induction principle? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$\delta$ in the proof is arbitrary ordinal, so we have shown that $\delta$-function exists for *any* ordinal $\delta$. By the lemma in the proof, we can merge all $\delta$-function into a single one, and it gives a class function we desired.

Your Theorem 8.9 also states that we can define not only a function over the class of all ordinals but also a function of the domain $\delta$ recursively. This is the reason why the proof flows in this way.

Comment: I don't get it.. what does $A=\mathscr{O}$ have to do with this though?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio You may take $A$ as a collection of all ordinals $\gamma$ such that $\gamma$-function exists.

Comment: You mean, given that $\mathscr{O}$ is the set of all ordinals, $A$ is the set of all ordinals in $\delta^+$ for which there is a $γ$-function exists and since they are equal I can say that for any ordinal there is a $γ$-function, and therefore, there is a $γ$-function for $\delta$ since is an ordinal?

Comment: @AndreaBurgio In the case of $\delta$-version of the proof, it would be better to take $A$ as the class of all ordinals $\gamma \le\delta$ such that $\gamma$-function exists, or $\gamma>\delta$. This is because we do not know $h$ is well-defined for ordinals greater than $\delta$. (Alternatively, we may define $h$ arbitrarily for ordinals greater than $\delta$.)

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to define a function $F\colon\mathrm{Ord}\to V$ by recursion. We can prove by induction on $\alpha$ that there is a unique function $f_\alpha$ which can be $F\restriction\alpha$, and moreover, these are uniformly defined. That is, there is some formula $\psi(x,y,z)$ such that $f_\alpha$ is defined by $\psi(x,y,\alpha)$. Of course there may be other parameters fixed, I've omitted them.

Since we proved that this is the case for all $\alpha$, we can simply define $F(x)=y$ if and only if $\psi(x,y,x+1)$.

Comment: I think i understand.. is it because since $\delta \in \delta^+$ and we proved that for all $\gamma \in \delta^+$ there is a $\gamma$-function, that means that there is also a $\delta$-function? Even though I still don't get what the conclusion of theorem 8.1 $A=\mathscr{O}$ has to do with this conclusion..

Comment: The conclusion of the induction theorem says that if $A$ is a class of ordinals such that $\delta\subseteq A$ implies $\delta\in A$, then $A=\mathrm{Ord}$. Therefore it means that we proved that **for every ordinal** there is a unique suitable function.

Comment: But how does $A=\{\gamma \in \delta^+$: $\gamma$-function exists$\}=\mathscr{O}$ is an ordinal implies that for every ordinal there is a unique suitable function? (I'm sorry for for all this question but I've been stuck for more than 2 hours and I don't know who to ask.. this is so frustrating)

Comment: Your induction hypothesis is wrong. Read my answer more carefully.